# Start a hidden panel with wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to start an app with several panels hidden from the user and show them per request when interacting with the menu.
So far the `budget_panel' that I want to be initially hidden is always on display.
My code is as follows (likely it can be dramatically improved as it is my first time using wxwidgets and OOP in Python).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sqlite3
import wx

class DB():
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

        self.cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE invoices (id INT PRIMARY KEY, client TEXT)')
        self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO invoices (client) VALUES ("Empresa A")')
        self.db.commit()

    def myget(self, id):
        return self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM {}'.format(id)).fetchall()

class BudgetPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.choices = ["Empresa A", "Empresa B"]
        self.choice = wx.Choice(parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, choices = self.choices)
        sizer.Add(self.choice)

class EmptyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent = parent)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Text', style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.TE_READONLY)

class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "Empresa",
                          size=(800,600)) 
        self.db = DB()
        self.menu()

        self.empty_panel = EmptyPanel(self)
        self.budget_panel = BudgetPanel(self)

        self.panels = {1000 : self.empty_panel, 2001 : self.budget_panel}

        for key in self.panels.keys():
            if key == 1000:
                self.panels[key].Show()
            else:
                self.panels[key].Hide()


        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.empty_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.budget_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)


    def menu(self):
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()

        main_menu = wx.Menu()
        budget_menu = main_menu.Append(2001, 'Presupuestos')

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.change_panel, budget_menu)

        menubar.Append(main_menu, '&Gestión')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

    def change_panel(self, event):
        for key in self.panels.keys():
            if event.GetId() == key:
                self.panels[key].Show()
            else:
                self.panels[key].Hide()

        self.Layout()


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
'''
```

Comment: your error is `here`: `self.choice = wx.Choice(parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, choices = self.choices)` change `parent` to `self`. Add `Vacío` to the menu options or you are stuck in the `Presupuestos` panel. The style entries on the statictext are for a textctrl, so are probably ignored.

Comment: Exactly that! Thanks!